# SAPUI5 SmartTable itemPressed - get pressed cell

Tags: sapui5

is there any chance to get the value of the pressed cell in the itemPress event ? I would like to set a tooltip when somebody presses a cell in a column. Alternatively, is it possible to register this event on a cell only ?

I am using SmartTable (responsive -> sap.m.table) based on XML View:

```
                <smartTable:SmartTable
                                id="kubas"
                                entitySet="myEntity"
                                initiallyVisibleFields="absender,empfaenger,nachtyp"
                                smartFilterId="smartFilterBar" 
                                tableType="ResponsiveTable" 
                                useExportToExcel="true" 
                                useVariantManagement="true" 
                                useTablePersonalisation="true" 
                                header="Entries" 
                                showRowCount="true" 
                                persistencyKey="SmartTableAnalytical_Explored" 
                                enableAutoBinding="true" 
                                demandPopin="true" 
                                class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding"
                                dataReceived="onDataReceived"
                                >

            </smartTable:SmartTable>
```

Or would it be better to somehow incorporate an icon / image to the cells value and set the tooltip for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally not a very good practice to set tooptip by itemPress event of a cell.

Either you can set a tooltip in Column header or you can customize your Column item showing tooltip.

You can customize your inner table of `SmartTable`, for example, Column header and Column item like below. More info please see [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smarttable.mtableCustom/code).

```
<smartTable:SmartTable entitySet="LineItemsSet"
    smartFilterId="smartFilterBar" tableType="ResponsiveTable"
    useExportToExcel="true" useVariantManagement="false"
    useTablePersonalisation="true" header="Line Items" showRowCount="true"
    persistencyKey="SmartTableAnalytical_Explored" enableAutoBinding="true"
    demandPopin="true" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
    <Table>
        <columns>
            <Column width="100px" hAlign="Left">
                <customData>
                    <core:CustomData key="p13nData"
                        value='\{"columnKey": "Dmbtr", "maxLength": "5","columnIndex":"4", "leadingProperty": "Dmbtr"}' />
                </customData>
                <Text text="{/#LineItems/Dmbtr/@sap:label}" />
            </Column>
        </columns>
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem>
                <cells>
                    <Text
                        text="{Dmbtr}" />
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
    </Table>
</smartTable:SmartTable>
```

> Set tooltip for column header if you want to show general information regarding this column.

```
<columns>
    <Column width="100px" hAlign="Left">
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="p13nData"
                value='\{"columnKey": "Dmbtr", "maxLength": "5","columnIndex":"4", "leadingProperty": "Dmbtr"}' />
        </customData>
        <Text text="{/#LineItems/Dmbtr/@sap:label}" tooltip = "YOUR TOOLTIP"/>
    </Column>
</columns>
```

> Set tooltip for each individual cell.

```
<items>
    <ColumnListItem>
        <cells>
            <Text text="{Dmbtr}" tooltip = "YOUR TOOLTIP"/>
        </cells>
    </ColumnListItem>
</items>
```

Comment: if i do it like this, then nothing is loaded to this column from the entitySet, moreover if i deselect all columns and leave the only one i customized, the table show the error message that i should pick at least one column to load the data.

Comment: I managed to make it work, the issue was, that i deleted the leadingProperty which is needed to show the data. Thanks Allen again!

Comment: @Kubas I was caught up and planned to have a look into your issue. Now i am glad that it works :)

Answer (score 0):

One more thing though, when i wanted to add the second column i was unable to bind it, in terms, the data was not coming from my entitySet, the column remain empty. If i put a hardcoded text, then it gets popuplated. Any clue why ?

```
<Table growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true" >
<columns>
    <Column hAlign="Left" vAlign="Middle" visible="true" >
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="p13nData"
                value='\{"columnKey": "column1", "leadingProperty": "column1", "filterProperty": "column1", "columnIndex":"0"}' />
        </customData>
        <Text text="Column1" />
    </Column>
    <Column hAlign="Left" vAlign="Middle" visible="true" >
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="p13nData"
                value='\{"columnKey": "column2", "columnIndex":"1"}' />
        </customData>
        <Text text="Column2" />
    </Column>

</columns>
<items>
    <ColumnListItem>
        <cells>
               <HBox>
                    <core:Icon src="sap-icon://sys-help" />
                    <ToolbarSpacer width="5px"  />
                    <Text text="{column1}" tooltip="dasda" />
                </HBox>

        </cells>
         <cells>
              <Text text="{column2}" tooltip="dasda" />
        </cells>
    </ColumnListItem>
</items>
```

Comment: Same as above, leadingProperty was missing .. :)